What are some well established notions of convergence for sequences of stochastic matrices?
This is definitely an open ended question. You'll see that there aren't so many people asking about this kind of thing, so the community would benefit from a post touching on notions of "convergence of sequences of stochastic process".
I'm looking for references from analytical or statistical perspectives. Topological results concerning the set of stochastic kernels are also of primary interest. I'd be happy to learn of esoteric algebraic or geometric results too.
In case the notation is unfamiliar, I'll just declare it that for $a \leq b \in \mathbb{R},$ I write $[a..b] := [a,b]\cap \mathbb{Z},$ $[a..] := [a,\infty)\cap\mathbb{Z},$ and $[..b] := (-\infty, b]\cap \mathbb{Z}.$
I'm faced with a sequence of discrete-time, ergodic Markov chains
$$\tilde{X}_{n,t}.$$
For each $n \in [1..],$ and then for each time $t \in [0..],\tilde{X}_{n,t}$ occupies a state in $\tilde{\mathcal{X}}_n := [0..n].$
Next, I normalize this sequence by considering $X_{n,t} := \tilde{X}_{n,t} / n,$ a chain whose state space is $\mathcal{X}_n = n^{-1}\tilde{\mathcal{X}}_n$, the set of all $i/n$ such that $i \in [0..n].$
We'll notate the stochastic matrix (a.k.a. transition matrix, Markov matrix) of $X_n$ by $S_n.$
Now, suppose we take $n \rightarrow \infty.$ Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,1],$ and let $X := ([0,1], \mathcal{B});$ i.e., $X$ is the measurable space $([0,1], \mathcal{B}).$
In what sense, if any, does there exist some stochastic kernel $\kappa: X \rightarrow X$ such that one could write
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} S_n = \kappa?$$
It might also be good to mention that, in general, the sequence $S_n$ is being estimated, so the fullest theory would treat the case where we have a sequence $\hat{S}_n$ of random stochastic matrices. You can imagine how "random stochastic matrix" is an ineffective Google search term.
Finally, this question was spurred by my considerations of a particular stochastic cellular automaton (see also interacting particle system) operating on a sequence of Erdos-Renyi graphs, hence invoking graph limit theory. This question may be of interest to these folks too, hence they are tagged. If you're curious, this paper describes the model that sparked all this, and this other paper exemplifies the kind of results I would like to get, although since I want to handle Erdos-Renyi graphs (and eventually graphons), it is more realistic to develop regression techniques.
Thanks!
